# Modulus function in bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
for ((i=0; i<lenPT; i++)) do 
    if [[ $(($lenPT % 2))  == 0]] then
        P[i] = "$((K [0] * arrT[i] + K[2] * arrT[i+1]))" 
    else
        P[i] = "$((K[1]*arrT[i-1]+K[3]*arrT[i]))"
    fi
done
```

I got errors saying that *"syntax error in conditional expression"* and *"syntax error near 'then'"*.  What is the error in my conditional statement?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 11):

Space matters, see [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39136986/3266847). You also need a semicolon after the `[[ ]]` conditional if you want to put `then` on the same line.

Instead of the cumbersome `[[ $(( )) ... ]]` combination, you can use the (Bash-only) `(( ))` conditional, the contents of which are evaluated in an arithmetic context:

```
if ((lenPT % 2 == 0)); then
```

You don't even need `$lenPT` in this construct, `lenPT` is enough (see [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) in the manual for details).

Since the exit status of `((...))` is 1 (not successful) if the expression evaluates to 0, and 0 (successful) otherwise, you could swap the branches and shorten the condition a little:

```sh
if ((lenPT % 2)); then
    P[i]=$((K[1] * arrT[i-1] + K[3] * arrT[i]))
else
    P[i]=$((K[0] * arrT[i] + K[2] * arrT[i+1]))
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a space before `]]`.

```
   if [[ $(($lenPT % 2)) == 0 ]]; then
```

Answer (score 3):

The `if ... else` that depends on the value of `$lenPT` is *needless*, since `$lenPT` never changes within the loop.  The assignments are so similar the `if` logic can be replaced with arithmetic.  Example:

```
n=$((lenPT % 2))
for ((i=0; i<lenPT; i++)) 
do      
    P[i]="$((K[n] * arrT[i-n] + K[2+n] * arrT[i+1-n]))"
done
```

Comment: your logic processing is very smart, but you had not resolved the question yet. Integrate your logic processing with Benjamin W. and Barmar 's answer the final result is perfect :)

Comment: That assignment line in the for loop has syntax errors.

Comment: @BenjaminW. You are right, it does not use $(( )) in the array's index calculations.

Comment: @南山竹 That's not the problem, the index calculation is in an arithmetic context and works like this, but the assignment uses spaces around the `=` sign!

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for spotting that, fixed.